# Input validation with IsNumeric does not work

Tags: vba, validation, input, isnumeric

I am trying to do an input validation (Only Accept Numeric Value), however the code below does not seem to work properly. Can someone please shed a light.

Upon entering non-numerical Value, the MsgBox is somehow skipped and the sub routine goes straight to Error:

```
Sub Check()
Dim A As Integer

On Error GoTo Error
Do
    A = InputBox("Enter A Numerical Value:")
    If IsNumeric(A) Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please Enter A Numerical Value!")
    End If
Loop
Exit Sub

Error:
MsgBox "An Error Has Occured!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `Application.InputBox` and specify the `Type`?

Comment: `Dim A As String` - Then use `IsNumeric`

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, this is my first VBA project. I didn't know such feature exists. This is a big help!

Comment: @braX I tried changing A as String and it worked. However I'm still curious to know why Integer doesn't?

Comment: If the user enters a string then that will trigger a "type mismatch" runtime error when you try to assign it to `A` (because you declared A as `Integer` and that can't hold a string)- so your code goes directly to the error handler.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah, I see.. No wonder. Thanks all for the help! Appreciate it!